# How to export a react native app as .apk?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, apk

I'm new to react native, and I just built my first mobile app (a simple D&D  dice app).
but I'm not able and don't know how to export it now as an .apk file to install  it on my phone.
I've used  Visual studio code and Expo Go to make and test the app, but now I'm stuck, help would be much appreciated :)

I have tried a few youtube tutorials, but I just get a lot of errors

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to build android apk from my react-native project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35450777/how-to-build-android-apk-from-my-react-native-project)

Answer (score 2):

As you have Expo setup use the EAS CLI -

First, you need to set up the CLI on your PC please follow the steps

- npm install -g eas-cli
- eas login
- eas build:configure

https://docs.expo.dev/build/setup/

After that run the cmd as per your required platform-

> eas build --platform android

or

> eas build --platform ios

To only export the apk, ensure you have something similar in eas.json.
See [this expo doc for your reference](https://docs.expo.dev/build-reference/apk/)

```
{
  "build": {
    "preview": {
      "android": {
        "buildType": "apk"
      }
    },
    "preview2": {
      "android": {
        "gradleCommand": ":app:assembleRelease"
      }
    },
    "preview3": {
      "developmentClient": true
    },
    "production": {}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To generate the APK go to the root of the project in the terminal and run the below command:

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
```

Go to android directory:

```
cd android
```

Now in this android folder, run this command

```
./gradlew assembleDebug
```

You should find the apk file in the following:

```
yourProject/android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk
```

The thing is, this will generate a "debug apk" to generate a "Release APK" you will have to setup a signature for the APK, but this is only necessary when publishing to the stores, not to create a debug apk version.